# SlidingTabStrip with both custom Background and indicator in Android

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I use SlidingTabLayout which I grab it from [here](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html). There I found a almost a perfect solution for my tab problem. However, I still have some issues with this exapmle. The problem with that example is that it uses the same color for selected tabs and unselected ones. But I want to change the background of the tab when it is selected. I tried to put a selector background to generated tabs on **createDefaultTabView(Context context)** method in **SlidingTabLayout.java**
When I do that, indicators are just gone away. I tried to put that selector on **onDraw()** function in **SlidingTabStrip.java** but the result was the same.

So, can you tell me a way out?

By the way, I am using a ToolBar. This is why I use SligingTabStrip (as I read, TabHost cannot work with ToolBar). Maybe I am wrong with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of selected tab change the selector file like

> SlidingTabLayout.java

```
tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(
                    R.color.selector));
```

> selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/blue"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/green"/>
    <item android:color="#ccc"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: I don't mean the TextColor. It's the background of the textView that I am talking about. When I try to do this for background, indicator becomes gone.

Comment: tabView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_ab_example); <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/primaryColor" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/primaryColorDark" /></selector> try this.

Comment: No. It didn't work as well. It throws an exception as

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200ef

I think it is something with android:drawable= "@color/" annotation